# Mysql not reconnecting with JNDI Tomcat 6

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I am using JNDI with Tomcat6 to manage Mysql connections, my Catalina/domain.com/ROOT.xml has:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   username="db1" password="somepass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"             
   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?autoReconnect=true" maxActive="15" maxIdle="3"  
   maxWait="5000" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="20" />
```

I though autoReconnect will do the job reconnecting to database but it does not, after about 8 hours of inactivity my app spits out lost connection to database errors. Any ideas?

Thanks, Fedor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dont use `autoReconnect`. There are problems with it and [it's been deprecated](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,32231,32231). For example, you could have a disconnect/reconnect event happen while a thread is using the connection. I would instead have your connection pool test connections with `testOnBorrow` before passing them to the app. Here is an example:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="db1"
          password="somepass"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"
          maxActive="15"
          maxIdle="3"
          maxWait="5000"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="20"
          logAbandoned="true"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
          numTestsPerEvictionRun="10"
          testWhileIdle="true"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          testOnReturn="false"
          />
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that with Tomcat, you can use the more lightweight and efficient validationQuery of "/* ping \*/". See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat.html