# unable to connect connection No operations allowed after connection closed. error in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, tomcat7, jndi

Here I have the problem in connection issues.

I have a web service deployed in Tomcat 7. In the web service, I am using Filter and in the init(), method I am calling connection.

```
public static Connection connection = null;

    @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        connection = ConnectionFactoryJndi.getConnection(); 
        }
```

Now I am using the same connection object throughout the application. Thus in this way I am creating only one connection and executing sql query. It is running fine. But when I am accessing the service url; it is giving error "unable to connect; no operation after connection closed" I am also set maxWait="28800000" that is 8 hours;  maximum duration.
My question is how to keep it open throughout. or when I accessed the url it should not give the same error and able to connect automatically. I am using MySql.

Here is the server.xml conf -

```
  <Resource
        name="jdbc/xxxxx"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="200"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="28800000"
        username="xxx"
        password="xxxxx"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxxx" />
```

In the class ConnectionFactoryJndi class -

public Connection createConnection() {

```
Connection connection = null;
try {
try {
envContext = new InitialContext();
} catch (NamingException e) {
}
Context initContext = null;
try {
initContext = (Context) envContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
} catch (NamingException e) {
}
DataSource datasource = null;
try {
datasource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/xxxxxx");
} catch (NamingException e) {
System.out.println("Name not found");
}
connection = datasource.getConnection();
} catch (SQLException e) {
System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.");
}
return connection;
}
```

Please suggest best practices.

Thanks.

Server Log -

```
Dec 05, 2013 10:09:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServletAdaptor] in context with path [/IntellixWebApi] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.astroved.intellix.jdbc.dao.ClientDAO.getClientDetails(ClientDAO.java:44)
    at com.astroved.intellix.security.ValidateClient.isValidClient(ValidateClient.java:14)
    at com.astroved.intellix.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

However, It is coming due to connection failures; then not able to execute query.

ClientDao class -

```
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error in Client DAO class (unable to connect connection) "
                    + e.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error in Client DAO class (unable to Execute Query ) "
                    + e.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                client = new ClientTO();
                client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientid"));
                client.setClientUrl(rs.getString("clienturl"));
                client.setClientSecurityKey(rs
                        .getString("clientserviceapiKey"));

                clientList.add(client);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error in Client DAO class ( Error in iteration ) "
                    + e.getMessage());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        DbUtil.close(rs);
        DbUtil.close(statement);
        //DbUtil.close(connection);
    }
```

**private Connection connection = SecurityFilter.connection;**

Server.xml -

```
 <Resource
        name="jdbc/xxxxx"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="200"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWait="28800000"
        username="xxxxxx"
        password="xxxxxx"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/xxxxxx" />


  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Client DAO class-

```
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    try {
        connection = ConnectionFactoryJndi.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error in Client DnaReportDao class (unable to Execute Query ) "+ e.getMessage());

    }

    try {
            if(rs != null) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    codeValue = new DnaReportTO();
                    codeValue.setNature(rs.getString("Nature"));
                    codeValue.setInterestedSubject(rs.getString("InterestdSubject"));
                    codeValue.setTipToParent(rs.getString("TipsToParent"));
                }
            }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error in DnaReportDao class ( Error in iteration ) "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
} finally {
    DbUtil.close(rs);
    DbUtil.close(statement);
}
```

**Currenr Server Log**

```
Dec 05, 2013 12:22:22 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.astroved.intellix.resource.DnaReportResource, and Java type class com.astroved.intellix.resource.DnaReportResource, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.astroved.intellix.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.astroved.intellix.resource.DnaReportResource, and Java type class com.astroved.intellix.resource.DnaReportResource, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
    ... 27 more

ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
ERROR: Unable to Connect to Database.
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace as well.

Comment: Please post the tomcat logs

Comment: @Bennet updated tomcat logs.

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan updated tomcat logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the error that you have given here it seems that the connection is bring closed by the application. the error `no operation after connection closed` could really mean that something in your application is closing it. Without the logs it would be difficult to diagnose whats causing the problem.

---

The correct way to use a connection pool is to borrow a connection every time you need it. Never store a reference to the connection in you own class as a singleton or a static field. This is because the pool may recycle the connection after sometime and you will end up with a valid connection object which is shutdown. This may be the reason of your problems too. The right way to do it is as follows:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    try {
        connection = ConnectionFactoryJndi.getConnection(); //always do this everytime you need a conenction.
        statement = connection.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error in Client DAO class (unable to connect connection) "
                + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if(statement != null){
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        }else{
            //log error and return or throw exception
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error in Client DAO class (unable to Execute Query ) "
                + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if(rs != null){
            while (rs.next()) {
                client = new ClientTO();
                client.setClientId(rs.getInt("clientid"));
                client.setClientUrl(rs.getString("clienturl"));
                client.setClientSecurityKey(rs
                        .getString("clientserviceapiKey"));

                clientList.add(client);
            }
        }else{
            //log error and return or throw exception
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Error in Client DAO class ( Error in iteration ) "
                + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
    //close rs
    //close statement
    //never close a conenction
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did not used the service after 10 PM yesterday night. Now When I am trying to use it @10 PM; it is throwing the error. So Max Wait time is 8 hours is expired and I think it is automatically closed.

Comment: can you paste whats on line 44 in ClientDAO ".dao.ClientDAO.getClientDetails(ClientDAO.java:44)"

Comment: String query = "SELECT * FROM intelix.clientprofile where clientServiceApiKey ="+ "'" + apiKey + "'";
rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

Comment: is this whole is line 22. then the issue is probably that your statement is null. Have you created a statement object first using the connection object? the exception is that you have a null pointed exception. Am not sure what gave you an idea about connection closed error.

Comment: yes, statment is null because  
statement = connection.createStatement(); Here connection is null and thus logging a message 
Error in Client DAO class (unable to connect connection) No operations allowed after connection closed.

Comment: this is due to after 8 hours being idle; connection is closed.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong about connection pools. After 8 hours the connections object are purged. But that doesnot stop you from creating new connection objects when needed. The pool will create new objects when asked for if there are no old objects. This connection closed error comes only when you explicitly close a connection in code. With connection pools you are not supposed to close connections. Just borrow them and use them and return them.

Comment: But I did not closed the connection explicitly any where in the application. I closed only 
DbUtil.close(rs);
DbUtil.close(statement);

Comment: for that particular DAO class statement and resultset.

Comment: I am not using autoreconnect = true; is it a cause??? However some one is suggesting testonBorrow?? Please see this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842755/mysql-not-reconnecting-with-jndi-tomcat-6

Comment: you should use autoConnect option. Also check for nulls for statement and rs. the other link which you added provides a very verbose and good config options. You should use that. It has provision for abandoning dropped connections which is useful.

Comment: did u find any loop holes in the clientDAO. Moreover is there any problem while using static and single instance of Connection object throughout the application. I am using due to performance. Please suggest.

Comment: are you using a static instance of conenctions? Thats very wrong. Check the answer edit. I have added a pseudo code for the right way.

Comment: Yes, as in the question I mentioned I have used static Connection to make use of all over the application directly. If no; then what would be the best way to get the single instance of Connection every where in application. Please.

Comment: But it will create each connection per request. This may cause performance issue and if I tried on Apache Jmeter; connection refused error etc will be coming up.

Comment: You should not use a single instance of continence everywhere in the app. The thing is that a Connection is a resource. You cant keep it alive for very long. If you use a single instance everywhere the your app is bound to the this problem. The correct approach and best practice is to use a connection pool. The idea of the pool is that you free the app of the headache of managing connections. Your pool will manage creation and closures of connections objects for you.

Comment: I am storing the Connection object instance in the Filter servlet by initializing in the init() method for one time. and assigning it in a static variable. Then calling all over the application same connection object.

Comment: it wont create a new connection per request. Thats is what the idea of the pool is. reuse connections. You should read about connection pooling a bit.

Comment: Thanks Nazgul for your most appropriate help and for your time.

Comment: Will change as you suggested. Could i have your email id please; may disturb you if you wish :)

Comment: your approach is very wrong in using the connections. tr it with the edit i gave above and if in JMeter you see performance issues then just increase the max active connection limit in your pool. The pool blocks new connection requests if it has reached the limit, and keep them waiting until an existing client has returned the request. For heavy apps this can be a bottleneck. To fix the adjust your max active, max idle connection limit  to suit your needs.

Comment: its ok. Ping me here when you need.

Comment: Thanks; will ping you. A lot of thanks and as a mentor; will follow you.

Comment: for a start you should rate the answer if you find it helpful. :)

Comment: But after continious 4 to 5 times; it is giving same error. and "Unable to connect Database."

Comment: post our pool config and the full DAO method.

Comment: what is the max connection limit in mysql? By default its about 1 or so. You have set max active to 200 in your config. runt hsi query in mysql to see how much max connection does it allow. select @@max_connections; this value shoudl be 200 or more. if not then increase.

Comment: it is displaying 100.

Comment: try with 80 connections only. In JMeter how many user threads have you set?

Comment: 1000 concurrent users with 10 loop

Comment: ha ha...its too big. Do with 80 max active for now. your tests may show its a slow but you should not see any connection errors now.

Comment: it is also giving 502 error; continious accessing with browser more than 10 times..

Comment: when I am changing it to 80; server is getting down nearly after 10 continuous request and throwing 502 error.

Comment: try ti increase the mysql connection limit to 200 now on mysql side and also in your pool config

Comment: Hi, i did it and it is running fine. But as you told not to close the connection; if i am following it is not working. When I am closing the connection; it is working fine. I increased maxActive to  300 in mysql and in tomcat 250. is it ok to handle 1000 users with 5 times.

Comment: yes its ok. You just need to make sure that mysql can handle those many concurrent connections. Rest is all cool.

Comment: I think you are by mistake written in your code in finally block " //never close a conenction". Is it true?? if I am not closing it means after two or three request it is throwing error.

Comment: Hey Nazgul, I used the same as you suggested but again the same error is coming up in next days of deployments; "Error in Client DAO class (unable to connect connection) No operations allowed after connection closed."; what is wrong in the code. ???

Comment: @Kumar "Never close the connection" is completely incorrect. It must be closed to release it back to the connection pool. -1 for this major error.

Comment: @EJP: if you start closing connection yourself then what the idea of having a connection pool? You let the pool handle the connection management handling. When the app shuts down a pool shutdown hook unregisters the connections if you have set the pool the right way.

Comment: @Nazgar You must close the connection to release it to the pool. That's how the pool works. The underlying connection isn't closed, but if you don't close the Connection the pool gives you, which wraps the underlying connection, you will have a connection leak. You don't appear to have ever done this.

Comment: That depends on which connection pooling implementation you use. most professional pools don't enforce the users to close the connection. Its a very subjective question 'close connection or not'. While frameworks like spring will handle it for you, others may not. Depends on how you are using the connections. raw SQL Connections or through a datasource.

Comment: YOu need not close the connection when using connection pool. CP is smart enough to close or keep open the connection. Overall a great piece of discussion so much info.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using the same connection object throughout the application

This won't work. You should be using a connection pool. Or else you have to do two things yourself that a connection pool would automatically avoid:

1. Ensure liveness of the connection every time you use it, and
2. Ensure single-threaded use of the connection, which completely destroys the performance of your server.

Don't do this. Use the Tomcat connection pool. It's easy.

Comment: I am using JNDI JNDI Connection Pooling in tomcat 7. Thus  getting good performance. I think by mistake he mentioned in the code vlock.Any way I am closing the connection. Otherwise it was hanging after 4-5 loop of connections. Thanks for your update.